# How to control 12 V with Arduino's 5 V pins?

Tags: arduino, transistors, eeprom

I'm trying to program a parallel EEPROM which requires Vpp high voltage cycle to write a byte. I want to control Vpp with an Arduino pin so I can write a byte onto an address in EEPROM. But I couldn't do it. In fact I tried to control Vpp with an NPN transistor but it burned up. How can I overcome this ? (I'm using Arduino Nano.)

Comment: Did you set resistor between arduino output an transistor base?

Comment: npn is a low side control.  would need a pullup to use.  Also check the current specs of the device against your resistor choices.

Comment: can you share a schematic for pull-up resistor ? where should i apply it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably didn't limit the current passing through the transistor.

Your goal is achieved by a simple "inverter" topology.

[image: BJT Inverter]

<sub>(Image source: [California Polytechnic State University, EE307, Fall Quarter 2003, MoHAT Projects, Group 2](https://courseware.ee.calpoly.edu/%7Edbraun/courses/ee307/F03/2/01_02_ArchanaDatla,MichaelCasanova.html))</sub>

Where Vin is your 5V pin and VCC is the 12V source. Rc avoids a very large current passing through the transistor. Please note that (as in all inverters) when the input is high, the output will be low, as the current passes through Rc causing a voltage drop. Similarly, when the input is low, the output will be high, as no current passes through the resistor and there is no voltage drop.

Comment: should i tie the negative terminal of the 12V supply to the arduino's ground  ?

Comment: Yes, of course! Ground, in most contexts, means a certain reference voltage. The 12V we are talking about are in reference to that voltage, and so that the 5V from the Arduino can be seen as 5V by the transistor, they must share that reference! So, as every point of the circuit is some volts higher or lower than the reference, this ground becomes our 0V reference.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked.

Comment: Always happy to help :)